# Matching against groups in different order without repeating the group but separated

Tags: java, regex

I would like to match some things that are grouped, but also comma separated. I need them not to repeat. I thought I had it, but as things started getting odd looking, I decided to ask. These search items are super simplified because in the real search there are all sorts of specific characters and words, and special characters and escaped characters. This is just so this example can be used to ask about.

```
{A=1,B=2,C=3}
{B=2,A=1,C=3}
{C=3,B=2,A=1}
```

This is what I tried:

```
^\{(?:(?:A=1,?)()|(?:B\=2,?)()|(?:C\=3,?)()){3}\1\2\3\}$
```

This uses some non-capturing groups followed by empty capturing groups in order to handle the uniqueness. I am not sure if this is the right way to go about things as it feels more like a parlor trick, but it is what I could find to get me this far.

This will succeed if they are in a different order

```
{B=2,A=1,C=3}
```

It will not match for duplicated (as it shouldn't)

```
{A=1,B=2,A=1}
```

Unfortunately, it will match when the comma is missing (not as intended).

```
{A=1B=2C=3}
```

I do get that `,?` gets the comma or nothing, but I can't see how to do it otherwise in this situation to have it not on the last one. Especially when matching in this strange way.

Comment: Once you match, what do you plan to do with the information?  I suspect that there may be more efficient ways to detect duplicates and store the matching information.  But your constraints are not very well defined.  Are commas always present or not?  e.g `(B=2,A=1,C=3}` vs `{B=2A=1,C=3}`.  What about `{A=2,B=2,C=3}`?  Do you want to save the individual elements e.g `B=2`).  Are they always in the form of `String=number`?  Are `{A=1,B=2,C=3}, {B=2,A=1,C=3},
{C=3,B=2,A=1}`, considered duplicates of each other?  Can you provide examples of inputs vs expected outputs/matches?

Comment: @WJS, I tried to be clear that the A=1 etc were just to get the point across as to where my matching was lacking. I am already doing all sorts of matching of each part. Think of something akin to a database record {Name="Grover The Monster", Address="123 Sesamee St", Employer="Corporation for Public Broadcasting", Employee Identification Number="12345-abcdef3-01ba-ffdd"} Something like that. However, none of which is germane to my question, so I tried to eliminate such things. Sorry for any confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Revising my regex based on your comment that you don't want repeats of alternations and your actual problem might be more complex.

Here is a refactored and more efficient version of your attempted regex:

```bash
^\{(?:(?:A=1()|B=2()|C=3())(?>,|\}$)){3}\1\2\3$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zLTjjo/3)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `\{`: Match a `{`
- `(?:` start non-capture group

  - `(A=1()|B=2()|C=3())`: Match one of `A=1` or `B=2` or `C=3` substrings and capture each alternation in empty capture groups 1,2,3
  - `(?>`: Start an atomic group that discards backtracking positions
    once matched

    - `,`: Match a comma
    - `|`: OR
    - `\}$`: Match closing `}` and end position
  - `)`: atomic group
- `){3}`: End non-capture group. Repeat this group exactly 3 times
- `\1\2\3`: Back reference of 3 empty capture groups to make sure that we have matched each of the alternation exactly once
- `$`: End

Comment: I like this solution to the extent that it doesn't use all the non-capturing groups, however, though I see it working in the example, applying it to my much larger problem seems like it would be cumbersome. The duplication over and over with much longer and more groups would make for a maintenance nightmare in my opinion.  I may attempt this in the future, but for now I will be selecting the other answer since I was able to fit it right into my existing regex.

Comment: ok understand and that's a fair point. I have now revised my answer and came up with a more efficient and shorter regex for the approach you have shown in question.

Comment: This now seems cleaner, and shorter in practice. And it works with my actual tests and code.

Answer (score 4):

> I do get that ,? gets the comma or nothing, but I can't see how to do it otherwise in this situation to have it not on the last one.

The key here is that it is contextual whether you want that comma or not.  You *do not* want it when the next character in the input is a `}` (but your pattern nevertheless allows it), otherwise you *do* want it.  You can use lookahead assertions to achieve that: `,(?!\})` matches a comma that is not followed by a `}`, whereas `(?=\})` matches nothing when the next character is a `}`.  Neither captures anything.  Combining those, `(?:,(?!\})|(?=\}))` achieves what `,?` cannot.

The full pattern is then:

```
^\{(?:(?:A\=1(?:,(?!\})|(?=\})))()|(?:B\=2(?:,(?!\})|(?=\})))()|(?:C\=3(?:,(?!\})|(?=\})))()){3}\1\2\3\}$
```

This retains your trick of capturing empty groups to ensure that each alternative matches once, without duplicating the individual items.

Comment: This solution was easy enough to quickly slip into the existing infrastructure I had. It works in my examples, so I will go with it. Thanks!!

Comment: A detail: there's no need to escape the equals sign.

Comment: Agreed, @CarySwoveland.  But I chose not to focus on that detail because the OP says that the regex they present is a much-simplified example.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment above I thought I would show this.  It still uses regexes but also builds a list of maps.  Duplicates aren't a problem since they will just be replaced with the earlier one in each map. Perhaps there is something here you can use.

```
List<String> list = List.of("{A=1,B=2,C=3}", "{B=2,A=1,C=3}",
        "{C=3,B=2,A=1}", "{C=3,B=2,A=1}", "{C=3,A=1,A=1}",
        "{C=3,B=2,A=1}", "{C=3,B=3,A=1}", "{C=3,B=2,C=3}",
        "{C=3,C=3,A=1}", "{C=3,B=2,B=2}", "{C=3,B=2,A=1}");

List<Map<String, String>> result = list.stream().map(s -> {
    s = s.replaceAll("[{}]", "");
    Map<String, String> groupMap = new HashMap<>();
    for (String grouping : s.split(",")) {
        String[] group = grouping.split("=");
        groupMap.put(group[0], group[1]);
    } ;
    return groupMap;
}).toList();

result.forEach(System.out::println);
```

prints

```
{A=1, B=2, C=3}
{A=1, B=2, C=3}
{A=1, B=2, C=3}
{A=1, B=2, C=3}
{A=1, C=3}
{A=1, B=2, C=3}
{A=1, B=3, C=3}
{B=2, C=3}
{A=1, C=3}
{B=2, C=3}
{A=1, B=2, C=3}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with four positive lookaheads:

```
\{(?=[A-Z]+=\d+,[A-Z]+=\d+,[A-Z]+=\d+\})(?=[^}]*\bA=1\b)(?=[^}]*\bB=2\b)(?=[^}]*\bC=3\b)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/EM3nrR/1)

- `\{` matches the opening brace and pins the subsequent lookaheads to that location;
- the positive lookahead `(?=[A-Z]+=\d+,[A-Z]+=\d+,[A-Z]+=\d+\})` ensures the brace-delimiting clause has the correct format;
- the positive lookahead `(?=[^}]*\bA=1\b)` ensures `"A=1"` is present before the closing brace;
- the positive lookahead `(?=[^}]*\bB=2\b)` ensures `"B=2"` is present before the closing brace; and
- the positive lookahead `(?=[^}]*\bC=3\b)` ensures `"C=3"` is present before the closing brace.

---

The opening brace will be matched if all four lookaheads are satisfied, but that's neither here nor there; whether there is a match is all that matters.

---

To instead match permutations of `{AU=17,BVW=2,CXYZ=321}`, say, only the last three lookaheads need be changed:

```
\{(?=[A-Z]+=\d+,[A-Z]+=\d+,[A-Z]+=\d+\})(?=[^}]*\bAU=17\b)(?=[^}]*\bBVW=2\b)(?=[^}]*\bCXYZ=321\b)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ccxaHd/1)